# Animated Scroll Image to a particular position on a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

For example:

1)i Have a div 100px*900px

2) i have an image 100px*200px

what i want is i want to move my image the exact number of pixels i scroll up or down

Can any one tell me 
 **Update**
 Check this. 
I want to move that image also when i scroll down animatedly(slowly) not fixed position.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? or show us some code.. or live example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cugdZ/6/

Comment: I want to move that image along with the scroll but, when i use <!DOCTYPE html>(i.e. html5 that image is not moving.
and i want to move that image animatedly(i.e. slowly)

Comment: Have you looked at the answer I submitted? It uses jQuery animate to move your image and explains what variable you want to read to know how much the page has scrolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the [`scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollY) property on the `window` object in Javascript. This holds the amount the window has scrolled.

You can then use something like [jQuery .animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to move your image the desired amount.

`$('#yourImage').animate({"top":window.scrollY+"px"});`

Note: This code assumes your image is absolutely positioned.

**EDIT**

```
$(window).scroll(function(data){
    //It is important to use .stop() for this as otherwise every slight scroll will add the animation to the animation queue.
    //What you want is for it to forget the others and go to the latest scroll position
    $('#im').stop().animate({"top":(window.scrollY + 10)+"px"}, 500);
});
```

This code will move an image every time the scroll event is triggered. I have tested this in Firefox using [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cugdZ/12/)

Comment: I couldn't find scrollX and scrollY in winodow object. Inspite of that i found Scroll so i used that. can you give me a detailed solution please check the jsfiddle link and check my code. http://jsfiddle.net/cugdZ/6/

Comment: `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` should definitely be there. What browser are you using? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cugdZ/12/) is an update to your fiddle. I have updated my answer to reflect the change.